# Matching regex on parameter in subroutine

Tags: regex, perl

I have a strange problem with a subroutine I wrote that should take out a certain time and print it in a certain format. The problem is that the $hours, $minutes and $seconds variables seem to be uninitialized but normally they should get the values according to my regex.

This is the code I use:

```
parse_datetime1("12:05:30");

sub parse_datetime1 {
    my $n = scalar(@_);
    print "scalar $n\n";
    foreach my $item (@_){
        print "An item: $item\n";
    }
    my $time = (@_);
    $time =~ m/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/;
    my ($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = ($1, $2, $3);
    print "Hours : $hours, Minutes: $minutes, Second: $seconds\n";
}
```

This is the output:

```
scalar 1
An item: 12:05:30
Use of uninitialized value $hours in concatenation (.) or string at ./test_dst.pl line 56.
Use of uninitialized value $minutes in concatenation (.) or string at ./test_dst.pl line 56.
Use of uninitialized value $seconds in concatenation (.) or string at ./test_dst.pl line 56.
Hours : , Minutes: , Second:
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to take first element of `@_` array, make a list on the left side of assignment and thus making list context,

```
my ($time) = @_;
```

instead of

```
my $time = (@_);
```

as later has implicit scalar context, and just returns size of `@_` array.